# GetFiles - Explanation

Tags: c#

Can anyone tell me what this code does? Thanks in advance!

```
string[] fileName = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.pdf")
                           .Select(fi => fi.Name)
                           .FirstOrDefault(name => name != "Thumbs.db")
                           .Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: It gets the first `.pdf` file that isn't named `Thumbs.db` ... Which makes little sense.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! No I think there wouldn't be a db file. How would it make more sense? :)

Comment: How many *.pdf would be a *.db ?

Comment: I think no one.

Comment: Aside from that, it will segment the name on `-` but it is also prepared to Split() a `null` value. I suggest you ignore/delete this code. It just isn't very good.

Comment: Most likely the `"*.pdf"` filter was added later and the author forgot to remove the `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: Your post is probably attracting downvotes because of the blatant "what does this code do" question.  It might be better if you told us what part of the code was giving you problems.

Comment: To answer your question: It will get info on all the files (from wherever it's looking) whose name matches `*.pdf`, then it will select the name of each of those files.  Then (ignoring any *.pdf files that are named thumbs.db (i.e., none)), it take that list of names and return either the first one, or `null` if the list is empty.  If there was a name, it will split the name up wherever there is a hyphen (1 hyphen will yield two substrings, 2 will give 3), returning an array.  If the list of names was empty, it will throw an exception.  This is poorly written code.  What are you trying to do

Answer (score 1):

**Method Chaining**

The code looks a little confusing possibly because it's using "Method Chaining", where the return value from one method is immediately acted upon without capturing the object into a named variable first.

For example, the `string` class has a `ToLower()` method which can be used to get the lowercase version of the string. If we have a method that returns a string (say, `GetUserName()`), then instead of doing this:

```
string userName = GetUserName();
string lowerCaseUserName = userName.ToLower();
```

We can just do this:

```
string lowerCaseUserName = GetUserName().ToLower();
```

If you understand that, then we can break the method chain down into individual lines and see what each one does.

---

**Break the chain into individual lines**

It's often helpful when debugging to break a method chain into individual lines, so you can examine each value along the way.

The first line gets an array of `FileInfo` objects from a directory (assuming `dirInfo` is an instance of the `DirectoryInfo` class), one for each file whose `FullName` ends with ".pdf"

```
FileInfo[] allPdfFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.pdf");
```

---

Then next line selects the `Name` property from each `FileInfo` object above (which is just the file name without the rest of the path) and returns them in an `IEnumerable<string>`.

```
IEnumerable<string> pdfFileNames = allPdfFiles.Select(fi => fi.Name);
```

**Note** if the line above seems confusing, it's probably the lambda expression passed to the `Select` statement. You can read this as "for each `FileInfo` object in `allPdfFiles`, which in this case is referred to as `fi`, select the `Name` property.

---

Next we select the first file name that doesn't equal `"Thumbs.db"` (or a default value of null if none are found that meet this condition). This line is not needed, since we know all the file names end in ".pdf"

```
string firstPdfFileName = pdfFileNames.FirstOrDefault(name => name != "Thumbs.db");
```

---

And finally we split the file name on the '-' character, remove any empty entries and return the pieces as an array. So if the file name was `"My-first-file.pdf"`, this would return an array of strings: `{"My", "first", "file.pdf"}`

```
string[] fileName = firstPdfFileName.Split(new[] {'-'}, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```